# Html Agility Pack - loop through rows and columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

How can I loop through table and row that have an attribute id or name to get inner text in deep down in each td cell? I work on asp.net, c#, and the newest html agility package.  Please guide.  Thank you.

An html file have several tables.  One of them has an attribute id=main-part.  In that identified table, there are many rows.  Some of those rows have same attribute name=display.  In those named rows, there are many columns which I have to extract text from.  Something like this:

```
<body>
<table>
...
</table>
<table>
...
</table>

<table id="main-part">
   <tr>
     <td></td>
     ...
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td></td>
     ...
   </tr>
   <tr name="display">
     <td>Jan</td>
     <td>Feb</td>
     <td>Mar</td>
     ...
   </tr>
      <tr name="display">
     <td>Apr</td>
     <td>May</td>
     <td>June</td>
     ...
   </tr>
      <tr name="display">
     <td>Jul</td>
     <td>Aug</td>
     <td>Sep</td>
     ...
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td></td>
     ...
   </tr>
   <tr name="display">
     <td>Oct</td>
     <td>Nov</td>
     <td>Dec</td>
     ...
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td></td>
     ...
   </tr>
</table>
<table>
...
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: please refer this link.An example as how to use htmlagility package.. [click here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1508198.aspx?PageIndex=2)

Comment: I followed the link and there is something interesting.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select these nodes using xpath:

```
foreach(HtmlNode cell in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//tr[@name='display']/td")
{
   // get cell data
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  
For the new package I got, I use DocumentNode in place of DocumentElement.

Answer (score 1):

It worked! Thank you very much Oded.

```
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
         doc.Load(@"C:/samplefolder/sample.htm"); 
foreach(HtmlNode cell in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@name='display']/td")) 
{
         string test = cell.InnerText;
         Response.Write(test); 
}
```

It showed result like **JanFebMarAprMayJuneJulAugSepOctNovDec**.  How can I sort them out, separate by a space or a tab?  Thank you.

Comment: perhaps this should be a new question? Anyways, when you do a `Response.Write`, you can add the comma at the end - `Response.Write(test + ",");`

Comment: you should also upvote and accept answers, if they did help. See the FAQ - http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: just use Response.WriteLine(test); INSTEAD OF Response.Write(test); and at the end of it all do a Response.ReadLine(); so you can see it and confirm it all is as you expect before pressing [Enter] to exit the screen.