# HtmlAgilityPack XPath Errors

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am attempting to parse a webpage using C# + XNA and HtmlAgilityPack, however when attempting to parse a table based on the examples in this post [HTML Agility pack - parsing tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655603/html-agility-pack-parsing-tables)

I run into some pretty strange issues. Here is my code slightly modified form the other post:

```
foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"))
{
    spriteBatch.DrawString(font, table.Id, new Vector2(0, num * 16), Color.Black);
    num++;
    foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
    {
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "row", new Vector2(0, num * 16), Color.Black);
        num++;
        foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("th|td"))
        {
            spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "cell: " + cell.InnerText, new Vector2(0, num * 16), Color.Black);
        }
    }

}
```

However when I hit the first line with a breakpoint I get a weird error I have taken a screenshot of my issue here: 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqWNw.png]

However if I remove the breakpoint I just get a NullReferenceException error when I hit the second foreach loop. I assume that i am not returning any actual tables with the XPath, but the first error is confusing me. If it is just an Xpath issue, I will spend some more time on that trying to understand how to use it.

here is the webpage i am trying to parse:

```
<div class="page">
    <header>

        <nav>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Score">Scoreboard</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section id="main">

<h2>High Scores</h2>
<div id="grid">
<table class="grid">
<thead>
<tr class="head">
<th scope="col">
    <a href="/Score?sort=Name&amp;sortdir=ASC">Name</a>
</th>

<th scope="col">
    <a href="/Score?sort=Points&amp;sortdir=DESC">Points</a>
</th>

<th scope="col">
    <a href="/Score?sort=Date&amp;sortdir=ASC">Date</a>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>sec_goat</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>9/8/1980 12:00:00 AM</td>
</tr>

<tr class="alt">
    <td>tankorsmash</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>10/10/2010 12:00:00 AM</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>sec_goat</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>8/12/2012 12:00:00 AM</td>
</tr>

<tr class="alt">
    <td>tankorsmash</td>
    <td>10000</td>
    <td>12/12/2012 12:00:00 AM</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>sec_goat</td>
    <td>100000</td>
    <td>1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM</td>
</tr>

<tr class="alt">
    <td>tankorsmash</td>
    <td>1000000</td>
    <td>9/18/2012 12:00:00 AM</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>bob</td>
    <td>99999999</td>
    <td>9/8/1980 12:00:00 AM</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I am fairly sure it is an issue with my XPath terminology. I used the path from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369294/html-agility-pack-loop-through-rows-and-columns) to grab Table rows and columns and it is working as intended.

Comment: I have realized the weird error I ma getting in the screenshot is related to the debugging, when I try to step into the XPath logic is when I get that error. Still not sure how to fix that, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following code, it works as expected:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(HTML);
foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"))
{
    foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("//tr"))
    {
        foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("th|td"))
        {
            //don't use .ChildNodes[1] in real code, only works for <th>.
            Debug.WriteLine(cell.ChildNodes[1].InnerHtml); 
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I changed the XPath statement from "tr" to "//tr". If you are interested to be more comfortable with XPath syntax, I would recommend you this page: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp