# how to loop through each node of HTML using HTMLAgilitypack and delete certain nodes?

Tags: c#, dom, html-agility-pack

I need to identify each node and delete certain nodes like `P`, `legend` ect..
Need to loop through following html using HTMLAgilityPack,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD><META content="IE=5.0000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">

<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor="white"><text><TITLE>ABCD</TITLE> 

<P style="page-break-before: always;">
<HR width="100%" size="3" align="CENTER" style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153);">

<fieldset>
    <legend>Personalia:</legend>
    Name: <input type="text"><br>
    Email: <input type="text"><br>
    Date of birth: <input type="text">
  </fieldset>

<P style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;"><FONT size="1">&nbsp;</FONT></P>
<P align="center" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;"><FONT size="2" 
style="font-family: Times New Roman;">B-17 </FONT></P></text>

</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369294/html-agility-pack-loop-through-rows-and-columns A possible duplicate, it's very similar to what you want. You haven't really specifically describe for what you want to compare so I can't really help you more.

Comment: There are tags like `P` `fieldset` `legend` ect.. All I need is to identify each tags individually and delete certain tags.

Comment: Based on which category u want to delete the tags ? is that inner text or tag id, name or what ?

Comment: Kavithai - Based on tag name i want to delete.

Comment: I believe it supports [xpath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) selectors, so it's quite simple to select whatever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm Just giving an example , Try with that

```
                String content = "Your Html page source as string";
                HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");
                HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(content);

                // Pass the name of the tag you want to remove 
                DeleteTagByName("tagname",doc);
                public void DeleteTagByName(string name, HtmlDocument HtmlDocument)
                 {
                     HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='" + name + "']").Remove();

                }
```

Comment: I have one issue but :( I just want the node to be deleted not the inner html or children nodes!

Comment: @Raghavendra you asked this and got answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467498/how-to-delete-a-html-tag-alone-but-not-inner-html-or-children-tag-using-htmlagil