# How to delete a html tag alone but not inner html or children tag using HTMLAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I need to delete an html tag say `<tbody>` in the following code,

```
<TABLE>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>    
    <TD></TD>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD></TD></TR>
  <TR>    
    <TD valign="bottom"></TD>
    <TD valign="bottom"></TD>
    <TD valign="bottom"></TD></TR>
  </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

I'm using,

```
      var document = new HtmlDocument();
      document.LoadHtml(<URL>);
      if (document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tbody") != null)
                {
                    document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tbody").Remove();
                }
```

But its deleting the entire  block instead of just  alone :(

Appreciate your help & time :)

Comment: You can't remove the tags from an element! Removing an element removes the tags as well as the content. So what is it you want to achieve? Tables in HTML do need their tbodies, you know. By putting the table rows directly in the table, you create an non-conforming DOM tree.

Answer (score 4):

```
var tbody = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tbody");
tbody.ParentNode.RemoveChild(tbody, keepGrandChildren: true);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<table>

  <tr>    
    <td valign="bottom"></td>
    <td valign="bottom"></td>
    <td valign="bottom"></td></tr>
  <tr>    
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td></tr>

</table>
```

Comment: If this command were not available, you would store the parent, store the child nodes, remove the node you want removed, and then add the child nodes back to the parent of the removed node.

Answer (score 1):

The inner html is an integral part of the tag, that's why the inner html is also getting deleted.

What you need to do is replace the `<tbody>` tag by the inner html of `<tbody>`, in your case, something like this (i did not check if this code works, but you get the idea):

```
document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table").innerHTML = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tbody").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give your  tags an id, you should be able to access the element by id.  This will make it super easy to delete.